# typo3 4.7 no backend (blank page)

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

I installed the current version of typo3 (4.7) on the IIS8. I wanted to login in the backend (../typo3/backend.php) but there is just a blank page. no errors nothing. In the source code I can see a lot of lines, but on the outside there is no page visible, no login nothing just blank.

Someone maybe has an idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Internet Explorer 8. It works fine in Firefox 16.x.

Answer (score 0):

To see what kind of an error produced the blank page it is very useful to
alter your /typo3/typo3conf/localconf.php
by adding

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = '1';
```